# SAVE Macro works on one machine, not on another

Tags: excel, vba

I have created an excel program to make sense of some raw data and sort into different sheets as needed. The last macro of the program is to save two worksheets as a new workbook into a shared folder on our domain.

The last macro works perfectly on my machine but does not on our Directors, the person that really needs this program. Here is the macro:

```
Sub SaveFile() 'Saves final worksheets as new workbook on S drive
Dim Path As String
Dim filename As String
Path = "S:\Administrative Staff\Membership Reports\"
filename = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("GRAND TOTALS").Range("A1")
Sheets(Array("GRAND TOTALS", "December 2018")).Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=Path & filename & ".xls", FileFormat:=xlNormal
End Sub
```

When I run my program on the Director's machine I get a "400" error after the two worksheets have copied to a new workbook. I have checked "Tools>References" to no avail...I'm thinking perhaps a security setting I'm missing or a group policy setting?

I'm stumped!

Comment: Does the Director have an S drive mapped?  Do they have permissions to save to that location?  What's the text of the error message?

Comment: check this points 1) Does drive S: exits for your directors 2) does he has sufficient permission 3) add exception handling to your code you will get error what is coming

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the reply. Yes, S drive is mapped on her machine, do have permissions, and the error message is simply "400". I don't think I'm familiar with exception handling?

Comment: `Option Explicit` at the top of the module may assist.

Comment: Do both machines use Windows? The Director isn't using a Mac by any chance?

Comment: Tried option explicit to no avail, and the Director is running the same version of Windows. I commented out the last line of the macro (ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs) and I don't receive an error. The program runs to completion. So I'm thinking it's some strange write property that I am unaware of...but I've checked what I know to check.

Comment: GOT IT. I added some error handler code. Turns out when our membership software exports the raw data we need to save it. We were both trying to name the report (via an input box at start of program) with the same name as the raw data file. Wow. I'm a little embarrassed. I could have figured it out by just trying a different report name at the beginning of the program. I appreciate everyone's help.